# Postgres cant vacuum despite enough space left (could not resize shared memory segment bytes)

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, vacuum

I have a docker-compose file with

```
postgres:
    container_name: second_postgres_container
    image: postgres:latest
    shm_size: 1g
```

and i wanted to vacuum a table, but got
`ERROR:  could not resize shared memory segment "/PostgreSQL.301371499" to 1073795648 bytes: No space left on device`

the first number is smaller than the right one, also i do have enough space on the server (only 32% is taken)

I wonder if it sees the docker container as not big enough (as it resizes on demand (?)) or where else could be the problem ?

note

```
docker ps  -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
95c689aa4d38        redis:latest        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   10 days ago         Up 10 days          0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp   second_redis_container
f9efc8fad63a        postgres:latest     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 weeks ago         Up 2 weeks          0.0.0.0:5433->5432/tcp   second_postgres_container

docker exec -it f9efc8fad63a df -h /dev/shm
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
shm             1.0G  2.4M 1022M   1% /dev/shm

df -m
Filesystem     1M-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev               16019      0     16019   0% /dev
tmpfs               3207    321      2887  11% /run
/dev/md1          450041 132951    294207  32% /
tmpfs              16035      0     16035   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  5      0         5   0% /run/lock
tmpfs              16035      0     16035   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs               3207      0      3207   0% /run/user/1000
overlay           450041 132951    294207  32% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/0abe6aee8caba5096bd53904c5d47628b281f5d12f0a9205ad41923215cf9c6f/merged
overlay           450041 132951    294207  32% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/6ab0dde3640b8f2108d545979ef0710ccf020e6b122abd372b6e37d3ced272cb/merged
```

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out (a friend helped :) )

i guess i cant count `1073795648` is slightly more then i needed for the vacuum so indeed shm size 10g instead of 1g helped

Answer (score 4):

That is a sign that parallel query is running out of memory. The cause may be restrictive settings for shared memory on the container.

You can work around the problem by setting `max_parallel_maintenance_workers` to 0. Then `VACUUM` won't use parallel workers.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\data\postgresql.conf` and scroll to

```
# - Asynchronous Behavior -
```

and add

```
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 0 # taken from max_parallel_workers
max_parallel_maintenance_workers = 0    # taken from max_parallel_workers
```

Work well!!